# PowerShell - Csv : foreach with conditions?

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, conditional-statements

I have to import a csv file, and I want to put a condition directly in the foreach.
I mean :

To read the csv, i do (yes my delimiter is \ ) :

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Delimiter \ -Path $mypath -Header 'column1', 'column2', 'column3'
```

Then i do :

```
foreach($line in $csv)
{
#Actions
}
```

What i would like to do, but I din't know if it's possible :

```
for($i =1; $i -lt $myarray.Length; $i++)
{
   foreach($line in $csv) | Where $line.column2 -eq $myarray[$i]
   {
      #Actions only if $line.column2 is equal to $myarray[$i]
   }
}
```

So i got an array, with names inside. And I want to do #Actions, only if a column in the csv, match to the information in my array. If not, I want to change of $line in $csv.

The idea i wrote looks so heavy, and I think there is a better and faster (harder and stronger #DaftPunk) way to do this.

If someone has already use this before, let me know :)

Thanks in advance,

Nico.

P.S : I apologize for my english ;)

EDIT : I've just realized that i can do a if condition :

```
for($i =1; $i -lt $myarray.Length; $i++)
{
   foreach($line in $csv)
   {
      if($line.column2 -eq $myarray[$i]
      {
         #Actions
      }
   }
}
```

But i still think that a :   | Where #Conditions, is better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IF inside the loop, here's a general approach

```
Import-Csv ... | Foreach-Object{

   if(something)
   {
      #do something with the current object and write it back to the pipeline
      $_ = ...
      $_
   }
   else
   {
      # write the object back to the pipeline
      $_
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll use this. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, **if ($.HeaderName -eq desiredValue) {} works, or where-object could too.